Prime Numbers $N=3+30k$
This is a starting question for a larger hypothesis on the building blocks of prime numbers and numerology.
Numerology plays an important part in the sequencing of prime numbers and it would b helpful for people to be able to contribute to the conversation.
Why is every number in this sequence not prime?
$$N = 3 + 30k$$
I have tested the first 20,000 and it holds true. (In case I have written the formula wrong)
$3+30=33$
$3+30+30=63$
$3+30+30+30=93$
$3+30+30+30+30=123$
$\ldots$
Is there another conjecture or theorem which includes this sequence?

Hint: They all share a common prime factor. What is it? Why does that happen?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property $30k + 3 = 3(10k+1)$

"Why is every number in this sequence not prime?" Um... because every number is divisble by $3$

"Is there another conjecture or theorem which includes this sequence?"  Um... what do you mean?  The conjecture "$3+30k > 29$" uses it.  So does "$3 + 30k$ is an integer".

What is the definition of a prime number?

Okay... taking off my sarcastic hat and putting on my Socratic teacher hat, I suppose the perfect socratic question would be "How do you know 33, 63, 93, 123$ etc are not prime".  (The answer I'm expecting is $33=3\times 11$ and $63=9\times 7$ and $93=3\times 31$ and $123=3\times 41$) and then I'd ask "What do all those factorizations have in common" (with a fixing) and ... so on.

I would b very interested and grateful to hear what you think and have the more technical aspects explained to me by experts like yourself.
The reason I found it interesting is because I have studied all the other prime numbers and there is a similar structure.
1, 11, 31 +30k = prime and non primes
3+30k = NON PRIMES
13, 23 +30 = primes and non primes
7, 17, 30 +30k = primes and non primes
19, 29, 30 +30k = primes and non primes
They all divide in to different numbers repeating in a sequence. Why is this the case when 3 is like it is.

Not all $31 + 30k$ are primes,  If $31+30\times 3=31+90=121=11^2$.  $3 + 30k=3\times (1+10k)$ so that can never be prime because its always divisible by $3$.  But others $19+30k$ are not always prime $19+30=7^2$.   Also for any $p + 30k$ if $k=p$ we will always have a non-prime as $p + 30p = p(1+30)=p\times 31$.

It sounds like you found an interesting pattern but your description is very hard to understand.  I don't know what you mean.

Here is one way to think about it.
For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows $3+30k\geq 33$, so $N\geq 33$.
Also, $N=3+30k=3(1+10k)$, where $1+10k\in\mathbb{N}$, which means that $N$ is always divisible by $3$.
Combining our findings, $N\geq 33$ and $N$ is divisible by $3$, while the only prime number divisible by $3$ is $3$ itself. All others primes are only divisible by $1$ and by themselves.
Therefore, $N$ can never be a prime number.
Hope this helps and please feel free to ask any further questions, if this is a bit unclear! :)

I would also like to share 1 fascinating fact about these divisors, if you divide any of these numbers by 9 you get a recurring number, .1, .2, etc. which equates to the numeric sum of its parts.
Eg,
1009 = 1+9 = 10 = 1+0 = 1
1009 ÷ 9 = 112.111
What r your opinions on numerology being a part of the discussion on primes? I would b very interested and grateful to hear what you think and have the more technical aspects explained to me by experts like yourself.
I have done a lot of work and I would fascinated and so thankful to hear what you have to say.

@Francis Well, I am far from being an expert, but if you are interested in prime numbers, it might be a good idea to talk to experts interested in number theory or consult some textbooks on this field. Good job on your findings about this sequence! Actually, this division by $9$ peculiarity applies to other integers as well! E.g. $1/9=0.111\dots$ or $5/9=0.555\dots$.

Dear Tom, in fact it applies to all prime numbers. I wonder what other divisors might reveal and whether this can b used to decode semi primes. My research has show when divided by 2 the primes of 9 for example are divided into two numbers centred on the decimal point, 9.5 and 4.5. These repeat throughout the sequence when looked at through the +30 prism. When multiplied together two 9.5 = 0.5, two 4.5 = 0.5 whilst a 9.5 and 4.5 equal 5.5. Whilst duplicates occur between separate number groups it still divides the possibly of which primes in half.

What does "the primes for $9$" and "centered on the decimal point, 9.5 and 4.5" mean?  What repeat throughout what sequence. What does "looked at through to +30 prims" mean?  What does "When multiplied together two 9.5 = 0.5, two 4.5 = 0.5 whilst a 9.5 and 4.5 equal 5.5" and "Whilst duplicates occur between separate number groups it still divides the possibly of which primes in half" mean? It sounds like you have found an interesting pattern but I can not understand what you are trying to say.

Are you familiar with the fact that ALL fractions when written in decimal will either repeat or end.  The repeating patter of $\frac a9$ will always be $a\times 0.11111....$ because $\frac 19 =0.11111....$  and as $\frac 17= 0.14285714285714285714285714285714...$ then $\frac a7 = a\times 0.142857142857...$ which always repeats.

Thank you so much for helping and I will do my best to explain because I think I have some answers.

I was actually reading a paper http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/papers/farey.pdf and realise this earlier.
One, thank you so much for helping and I will do my best to explain because I think I have some answers.
What I am explaining is this:
PRIME - DIVIDED BY 9 - NUMEROLOGICAL VALUE
97 - 10.77 - 9+7=16 then 1+6=7
101 - 11.22 - 1+0+1=2
103 - 11.44 - 1+0+3=4
107 - 11.88 - 1+0+7=8
109 - 12.11 - 1+0+9=10, 1+0=1
113 - 12.55 - 1+1+3=5
127 - 14.11 - 1+2+7=10, 1+0=1
131 - 14.55 - 1+3+1=5

I have divided the prime numbers up into 8 categories depending on how they react to being divided by three.                                 (a) 19÷3=6.33 whereas (b) 29÷3=9.6. A+30k / 3 is always 9.6 the other primes behave similarly
There are sequences in the primes which are easy to spot when you look at them this and include the non prime numbers.
(A) 19/2=9.5 (9.5)
(B) 49/2=24.5 (4.5)
(A) 79/2=39.5 (9.5)
(B) 109/2=54.5 (4.5)
(A) 139/2=69.5 (9.5)
If the primes weren’t ordered like this with the non primes the pattern would be harder to spot.

It appears that every number has particular building blocks.
The reason why it is interesting is because of the example at the top. If the division actually means something to the number, such as its numerological value, what do these other divisions mean!
If we look at a combination of 9 you will c what happens when we combine them.
(A)19 x (A) 79 = 150/2 =750.5(0.5)
(A)19 x (B) 109 = 2071/2 = 1035.5 (5.5)
(B) 109 x (B) 109 = 11881/2 = 5940.5 (0.5)
So the prime numbers combine to produce semi primes with different “decimal code” depending on where they came from in the list.
